# Zooming out dispositiong image with custom imageView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, swing

I am using following code to add a custom ImagView in a ViewPager to set Zooming system. On double Tap, You zoom in, and then on double tap again you zoom out. Now suppsoe you swipe and zoomed in a little bit, now I want the feature that if you now double tap it should zoom you out.

If i call function minZoomed() it zooms out but it does not centers the position now. However it does center the image if I first zoomed In fully and then double tap to zoom out. But when i zoom in a little using swipe and then try to zoom out, it displaces the image to some random places.I want the image to get centered in the screen after Zoom out

So

Firstly Total Zoom out(Centered)> Double Tap> Full Zoomed In (Centered) > Double Tap > Full zoomed out (centered)

But

Firstly Total Zoom out(Centered)> SWIPE TO ZOOM> Little Zoom (Centered) > Double Tap > Full zoomed out (Displaced)
How can I fix this issue?

```
public class ZoomImageView extends ImageView
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    boolean isMaxed = false;
    boolean zoomOut = false;

    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;

    float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;

    float width, height;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    GestureDetector mDoubleDetector;
    Context context;

    private CustomViewPager pager;

    public ZoomImageView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        mDoubleDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new DoubleTapGestureDetector());
        matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                mDoubleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) 
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG)
                        {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                            float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                            if (scaleWidth < width) 
                            {
                                deltaX = 0;
                                if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                    deltaY = -y;
                                else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                    deltaY = -(y + bottom); 
                            } 
                            else if (scaleHeight < height) 
                            {
                                deltaY = 0;
                                if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                    deltaX = -x;
                                else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                    deltaX = -(x + right);
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                    deltaX = -x;
                                else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                    deltaX = -(x + right);

                                if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                    deltaY = -y;
                                else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                    deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                            }
                            matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;

                        break;
                }
                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                if (saveScale == minScale)
                {
                    pager.setPagingEnabled(true);
                }
                else 
                {
                    pager.setPagingEnabled(false);
                }
                return true; 
            }

        });
    }

    public void setPager(CustomViewPager pager)
    {
        this.pager = pager;
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) 
    { 
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
        bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
    }

    public void minZoomed()
    {
        matrix.setScale(minScale,minScale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        invalidate();
        redundantYSpace = (float)height - (minScale * (float)bmHeight) ;
        redundantXSpace = (float)width - (minScale * (float)bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float)2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float)2;
        saveScale = minScale;
        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);
        origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void maxZoomed()
    {
        matrix.setScale(maxScale,maxScale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        redundantYSpace = (float)height - (maxScale * (float)bmHeight) ;
        redundantXSpace = (float)width - (maxScale * (float)bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float)2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float)2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);
        origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        invalidate();
        saveScale = maxScale;

    }   
    public void setMaxZoom(float x)
    {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    public void setMinZoom(float x)
    {
        minScale = x;
    }   

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) 
        {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            float mScaleFactor = (float)Math.min(Math.max(.95f, detector.getScaleFactor()), 1.05);
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale) 
            {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } 
            else if (saveScale < minScale)
            {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }
            right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
            bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
            if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height) 
            {
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) 
                {
                    matrix.getValues(m);
                    float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                    float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                    if (mScaleFactor < 1) 
                    {
                        if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width) 
                        {
                            if (y < -bottom)
                                matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                            else if (y > 0)
                                matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            if (x < -right) 
                                matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                            else if (x > 0) 
                                matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) 
                {
                    if (x < -right) 
                        matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                    else if (x > 0) 
                        matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    if (y < -bottom)
                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                    else if (y > 0)
                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        //Fit to screen.
        float scale;
        float scaleX =  (float)width / (float)bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float)height / (float)bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        saveScale = 1f;

        // Center the image
        redundantYSpace = (float)height - (scale * (float)bmHeight) ;
        redundantXSpace = (float)width - (scale * (float)bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float)2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float)2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);   
    }

    private class DoubleTapGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) 
        {

            if( isMaxed == false)
            {
                isMaxed = true;
                maxZoomed();
                pager.setPagingEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                isMaxed = false;
                minZoomed();
                pager.setPagingEnabled(true);
            }


            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at this project : https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom

It has pinch-to-zoom & double tap support and is very easy to implement (I've used it myself)

All credits go to **sephiroth74**

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link : http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c13/s5.html
(but not custom image view)

The program ( MandelbrotViewer.java) has zooming in/out features on tap.

(no external library needed)

zoom in :

[image]

More zoom :

[image]

[image]

zoom out:

[image]